# is there any equivalent method like req.session.destroy() in hapi js to destroy session?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I want to destroy session after user logout of my application. I know how to do it in *express* like `req.session.destroy()`. Is there any equivalent method like `req.session.destroy()` in *hapi.js* to destroy session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which plugin you're using.

For example, i use [hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) and there's a method `request.cookieAuth.clear()`